# Does Node.js API for PhantomJS support keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

Does this Node.js API for PhantomJS support keyboard events
https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom ? And if it's supported how can I use a keypress event?

Comment: The npm page states it's just a wrapper around phantomJS, so I suggest you look at the phantomJS docs and if that supports keyboard events

Comment: I already know that PhantomJS support keyboard events, but I am asking particularly regarding this API.